# list view is unable to display data from cloud firestore

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-cloud-firestore

*Here is my code behind*
*IIdentifiable is a interface that has Id as property.*
I am getting a nullrefrence exceptions while extracting data.

```
public abstract class SalonService<T> : ISalonService<T> where T : IIdentifiable
{

    public Task<T> GetSalonAsync(string id)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        FirebaseFirestore.Instance
            .Collection("salons")
            .Document(id)
            .Get()
            .AddOnCompleteListener(new OnDocumentCompleteListener<T>(tcs));

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public Task<IList<T>> GetSalonsAsync()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<T>>();
        var list = new List<T>();

        FirebaseFirestore.Instance
            .Collection("salons")
            .Get()
            .AddOnCompleteListener(new OnCollectionCompleteListener<T>(tcs));

        return tcs.Task;
    }

}
```

*And the service listeners for collection of data*

```
 public class OnCollectionCompleteListener<T> : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
    where T : IIdentifiable
{
    private System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<IList<T>> _tcs;

    public OnCollectionCompleteListener(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<IList<T>> tcs)
    {
        _tcs = tcs;
    }

    public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsSuccessful)
        {
            var docsObj = task.Result;
            if (docsObj is QuerySnapshot docs)
            {
                _tcs.TrySetResult(docs.Convert<T>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Service listener to display document*

```
public class OnDocumentCompleteListener<T> : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
    where T : IIdentifiable
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<T> _tcs;

    public OnDocumentCompleteListener(TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs)
    {
        _tcs = tcs;
    }

    public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsSuccessful)
        {
            var docObj = task.Result;
            if (docObj is DocumentSnapshot docRef)
            {
                _tcs.TrySetResult(docRef.Convert<T>());
                return;
            }
        }
        // something went wrong
        _tcs.TrySetResult(default);
    }
}
```

*The Document extension as well*

```
public static class DocumentReferenceExtensions
{
    public static T Convert<T>(this DocumentSnapshot doc) where T : IIdentifiable
    {
        try
        {
            var jsonStr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc.Data.ToDictionary());
            var item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonStr);
            item.Id = doc.Id;
            return item;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION THROWN");
        }
        return default;
    }

    public static List<T> Convert<T>(this QuerySnapshot docs) where T : IIdentifiable
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var doc in docs.Documents)
        {
            list.Add(doc.Convert<T>());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

*Please let me know what am I missing? I am stuck here*

Comment: which **specific** line throws the exception?

Comment: Hello @Sumityadu, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to edit your question to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it easier for the community to help you.

Comment: Please do more debugging, to *isolate* the problem. 1) Make sure the code works, if instead of calling cloud firestore, you simply display some dummy data. 2) Using breakpoints or Debug WriteLine, find out exactly what is being returned from firestore. And make sure to check any exceptions or error codes.